# My question was deleted but it isn't a duplicate

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions

[My question](https://superuser.com/questions/582360/how-to-change-explorers-default-location-via-the-registry) has been marked as a duplicate and deleted, but the question of which it supposedly is a duplicate doesn't answer my question. The solution given by **Molly7244** doesn't solve my problem on Windows 7. I should have mentioned what version of the operating system I am using.

Would it be possible to undelete my question? Then I would edit it to specify my OS' version.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Questions are auto-deleted when they're closed and negatively scored. I undeleted it for now, but it should be your duty to edit it and point out why it's not a duplicate of the other question, and why its answers don't apply. The community can then vote to re-open. You could also flag it for moderator attention to have it reviewed and reopened.

In the future, you should try to improve your questions as soon as possible if they're closed – you brought this up more than a month after your question was closed, so a deletion unfortunately was the next logical step here.